# Probability of two correlated numbers modulo p being part of a subset

Tags: probability, modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ be a prime number and $x$ be a number chosen uniformly at random from $0,...,p-1$ and let $y=cx \mod p$, where $c$ is some integer in $1,...,p-1$. Let's suppose we chose at random $p/2$ (rounded down) integers from the set $0,...,p-1$, and denote the numbers we chose $S$.

What is the probability of the event "$x$ and $y$ are in $S$"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only relevant information about $x$ and $y$ is whether $x=y$ or $x\ne y$. We have $x=y$ if $c=1$ and $x\ne y$ if $c\ne1$. Thus the probability is

$$
\textsf P(\text{$x$ and $y$ are in $S$})=\begin{cases}\frac{\lfloor\frac p2\rfloor}p&c=1\;,\\\frac{\lfloor\frac p2\rfloor(\lfloor\frac p2\rfloor-1)}{p(p-1)}&c\ne1\;.\end{cases}
$$